# Access database in C# console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

The current problem I'm having is an error message that it could not find file `C:`  now I dont know what the problem is because the file is in that location. I have I tried in both .accbd and .mbd.

```
private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()    
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    String connectionString = 
            @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OlEDB.4.0;"
            + @"Data Source= C:\Temp\F1\Docs\Expeditors Project\Table1.accbd";

    conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: read the contents of file separately and use the string in connectionString

Comment: .accbd? Is that not .accdb?

Comment: Still the same error @Ripple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you tried another Provider? 
For example:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=C:\Temp\F1\Docs\Expeditors Project\Table1.accbd;
```

Comment: Nice to hear that this helps

Answer (score 2):

try `\\` in `Data Source` Path

like below -

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\Data\test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `

```
    `private static OleDbConnection GetConnection() throws SQLException{
        { 
    if (conn==null) 
{ 
            try{                                                                                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            String connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OlEDB.4.0;"
                                      + @"Data Source= C:\Temp\F1\Docs\Expeditors Project\Table1.accbd";
            conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();

            return conn;
        }}
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```